# Ajax insert data into mysql

Tags: rest

I need to save some data into mysql, let´s say "LONDON" and I can use Javascript , jQuery and Ajax, but NO  node.js or PHP.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks,
R.

Comment: If you don't want to use node or php, how are you planning to insert the data in server side?

Comment: @AslanShemilov Why do you think one needs node or PHP to insert data on the server side?

Comment: I just suggested you php or node.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A solution for this problem would be to use the micro-services architecture and the RESTful Web Services.
Javascript could send the data to an URL and on the server side the data would be sent to the database.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to connect to MySQL server using only JavaScript, jQuery or Ajax directly because connecting to DB server to save or retrieve data is what server does which none of 3 can do alone.
However, there is service that does the server-like tasks for you.

https://www.dreamfactory.com/

Please take a look.

Comment: Since when does one need javascript, jquery or ajax to insert data into mysql on the server?